# How to compare two strings in C with the number of characters compared being the number of characters in a string received from a file

Tags: c, string, char

I am trying to create a "bank" program in C which has unique logins and to do so, I have a file of usernames and check if the username entered by the user matches a pre-existing one and have done so below

```
    FILE *pF = fopen("usernames.txt", "a+"); //opens 2nd file to read it, and creates it if it doesn't exist
    
    //int length = sizeof(userName) / sizeof(userName[0]);
    while (fgets(buffer, 255, pF)) { //reads file adn checks if the username is on it
        if (strncmp(buffer, userName, strlen(userName)) == 0) { //checks the amount of characters in the string userName and only compares those characters
            uniqueUsername = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

However my issue is that if a pre-existing username such as "Daniel" exists, you can't create "Dan" as another username.

I have tried changing `strlen(userName)` into `strlen(buffer)` but that compares all 255 characters of the buffer string (I created it as a dummy array of 255 bytes) and results in a no match. Are there any ways to overcome this issue?

Comment: @EricPostpischilÚ You said _"`fgets` does not null-terminate the data it reads, and it includes the newline character that ends the line"._  I disagree with the first point (about null termination — unless the buffer is of size zero, it null terminates the input).  The second is correct assuming there's enough space for  it; I don't worry much about that refinement  Would you delete and resubmit a corrected version of your comment?

Comment: If you want to pay attention to all the characters in the names, don't use `strncmp()` — use `strcmp()`.  It does precisely what you say you're after.  It will recognize that `"Dan"` and `"Daniel"` are different user names.  Don't forget to remove the newline read by and preserved by `fgets()`.

Comment: the strcmp function compares all 255 characters of my buffer variable which is defined as char buffer[255]; and compares all 255 characters which is filled with things that I am not sure why they exist such as '/377' which results in both the username and the buffer never being the same @JonathanLeffler

Comment: The `strcmp()` function stops comparing when it encounters a difference between the strings or when it reaches the first null byte in either string. If you have properly null-terminated your strings, `strcmp()` won't read beyond the end of your buffer. (If you haven't properly null-terminated your strings, you aren't really dealing with strings; they're just byte arrays.). The `fgets()` function null-terminates the strings it returns. Your code does not show how userName is defined, initialized or otherwise set up. If it is not a properly null-terminated string, you could run into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file contains the user names without leading or trailing spaces, one per line, you can just verify that in addition to a match with `strncmp`, the next character is a newline `'\n'`.

Here is a modified version:

```
// check user name against the list of user names
// return -1  if the file cannot be open
// return 0   if the userName already exists
// return 1   if the userName was appended
int check_username(const char *userName) {
    char buffer[256];
    int uniqueUsername = 1;
    size_t len = strlen(userName);
    FILE *pF = fopen("usernames.txt", "a+");
    if (pF == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pF)) {
        if (!strncmp(buffer, userName, len) && buffer[len] == '\n') {
            uniqueUsername = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (uniqueUsername) {
        // append the unique user name
        fprintf(pF, "%s\n", userName);
    }
    fclose(pF);
    return uniqueUsername;
}
```

Comment: Yep thank you your response helped me modify my code, where I slightly changed your 'if' statement to `if(strncmp(buffer, userName, strlen(userName)) == 0 && buffer[strlen(userName)+1] == '\n')`

Comment: @Aditya: it should be `buffer[strlen(userName)] == '\n'`, no `+1` needed.

Answer (score 1):

**Use `strcmp()` to test string uniqueness**

"with the number of characters compared being the number of characters in a string received from a file" is not a necessary requirement.
Simply compare strings. [@
Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600246/how-to-compare-two-strings-in-c-with-the-number-of-characters-compared-being-the/77600714#comment136804915_77600246)

```
    bool uniqueUsername = true;
    char buffer[255 + 1]; // One more for a potential '\n'.
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, pF)) {
      buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential '\n'.
      if (strcmp(buffer, userName) == 0) {
        uniqueUsername = false;
        break;
      }
    }
```

Comment: the strcmp function compares all 255 characters of my buffer variable which is defined as char buffer[255]; and compares all 255 characters which is filled with things that I am not sure why they exist such as '/377' which results in both the username and the buffer never being the same

Comment: @Aditya `strcmp()` does not do that.  `strcmp(a,b)` compares characters in that _strings_ pointed to by `a` and `b`.  That compare continues until a difference is found or a up to the _null character_.  255 has nothing to do with it the compare as it should not.  If you think that an upper bound of length is needed, there is either a problem in an unposted part of code or a mis-understanding of the issue.